# Some fields are not being saved in experience editor

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

I have a component that has following fields:
    Title
    Image
    Link Title
    Link

Among these fields, Title and Link Title are not being saved while editing in the Experience Editor, upon saving it reverts to the value from content editor.

However the other fields are correctly being saved.
Any advice, suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
p.s. using glass mapper

Comment: Did you check the logs to see if there is something useful there?

Comment: Are these fields in your page/item template or are the in a datasource item for the component?

Comment: The fields are in the datasource item. In the sitecore logs: Save item: master:/sitecore/content/SiteA/Home, language: en, version: 1, id: {guid of the home page item}.

Comment: Can you add the code from your view?

Comment: So this was happening because the carousel slide was breaking in the experience editor. Since in edit mode, the html structure was different i.e. not the background image thus this was breaking the whole carousel.